# How can I find which version of a particular mode I am using?

Tags: version-compatibilty

For example, I want to use a library that requires I am on org-mode version 8 or above. I don't know what version of org-mode I have.

Running `M-x version` only gives me the emacs version. Is there a command where I can get the org-mode version?

NOTE: As @Drew mentioned in the comments, I am searching for the version of a *package*, not a *mode*. In this example, I want to get the version of the org-mode *package*, not the version of org-mode itself.

Comment: `M-x org-version`?

Comment: Yep, that works! I guess it's slightly different for each mode? For example, to get the current `markdown-mode` version, I run `M-x markdown-show-version`. It'd be nice if there was a generic method, but I guess it is sufficient to just run `M-x <mode name>-version <TAB>` and the autocomplete should find the rest...

Comment: `M-x describe-package org`

Comment: Perfect! @xuchunyang if you post as an answer, I will gladly accept. Perhaps it will help future readers. If not, I'll just delete the question.

Comment: Packages and other libraries can have versions. Modes typically do not have versions. You might want to edit your question to clarify - it seems you are looking for the version of a *package*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use <kbd>C-h P</kbd> (`describe-package`). After entering a package name, the attributes (including version) of the package will be listed in the `*Help*` buffer. Besides, you can also view the version of a package from Package Menu (<kbd>M-x list-packages</kbd>).

Answer (score 3):

Packages aside, note that `M-x find-library` will take you to the source code for a given library name. Assuming the author has assigned a version, you will typically find that information specified in the comments at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this programmatically:

```
(require 'find-func)
(require 'lisp-mnt)

(defun get-library-version (library)
  "Return a version string for LIBRARY."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents (find-library-name library))
    (or (lm-header "package-version")
        (lm-header "version"))))
```

Here's an
example usage:

```
(get-library-version "auctex") ;=> "13.0.12"
```

Answer (score 0):

`M-x list-packages` takes you to a list of all the packages, including what you have installed and their version number.

For example, to look for `wc-mode`. I `C-s wc-mode`. Or I can click the "status" to sort the different packages in the order of "installed", "available" etc...